# C++: cannot open source file 2 layers deep

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include

I'm working on two interconnected projects in Visual Studio 2017.

The first project is `Wrapper`, comprised of `Wrapper.h` and `Wrapper.cpp`. `Wrapper` includes `ThirdParty.h`. I can compile/build `Wrapper` with no issues.

```
#include "ThirdParty.h"

std::string foo(){
    return "This is Third Party text";
}
```

The second project is `Principal`, comprised of `Principal.h` and `Principal.cpp`. `Principal` includes `Wrapper`.

```
#include "Wrapper.h"

std::string bar(){
    return Wrapper.foo() + "\nThis is Wrapper text";
}

// Expected output:
//This is Third Party text
//This is Wrapper text
```

However, when I try to build `Principal`, I am informed that it cannot open `ThirdParty.h` (and also can't see the types etc. used within).

I have tried including the directory where `ThirdParty` is stored under `Properties` > `C/C++` > `General` > `Additional include directories`, but that makes no difference. I have checked the compilation settings, everything is being compiled as `Release`/`x64` as intended.

What should I do?

Edit:
Here is the command line:

> /permissive- /MP /GS /GL /analyze- /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t
> /I"C:\path\to\ThirdParty" /I"C:\Path\To\Wrapper" /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl-
> /Fd"Release\vc141.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_MBCS"
> /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy- /Oi /MD /FC
> /Fa"Release" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Release" /Fp"Release\principal.pch"
> /diagnostics:classic

Comment: You did something wrong in your `Additional include directories` setting. Maybe you did not apply it to all configurations of your `Principal` project. Maybe you mistyped the path. if you used a relative path its relative to the current project.

Comment: @drscherjm So I should add `ThirdParty` to the additional include directories?

Comment: @drescherjm I even tried the absolute path (copy/pasted from file viewer) and that did not work

Comment: The path to `ThirdParty` should be added to the additional include directories setting of all configurations of `Principal`. However again if you use a relative path make sure you use the correct relative path from the folder the project file for `Principal` exists inside.

Comment: If there are any spaces in the path you may have to quote them. I never use paths with spaces in when programming in `c++`

Comment: Also `Additional include directories` paths are configured per configuration (Debug/Release) and per platform (Win32/x64). make sure you have corrected settings for the configuration and platform you are actually building.

Comment: @dewaffled that was my first idea, but everything is being compiled as Release/Win32 as it should be

Comment: @drescherjm I have revised all my paths, no spaces and still no luck

Comment: You may have to look at the actual command line passed to the compiler.

Comment: BTW, I do use projects with more than 2 dependent libraries (which you call 2 layers deep) and there is nothing special that I need to do to make it work.

Comment: @2785528 It literally crashes at the line "`include XXX`" but I'll throw in a hello world line if it'll sweeten he deal

Comment: I think you need to add your project properties `c++->Command Line` for the `Principal` project. That may help us help you debug the problem.

Comment: @drescherjm I added the command line if that's any help

Comment: I don't see why it fails sorry.

Comment: If you have not already do a clean build.

Comment: @drescherjm I did, but didn't change anything, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could try to check the following points:

1,`ThirdParty.h` should be included in the `Wrapper.h` file instead of `Wrapper.cpp` file.

2,The absolute path of `ThirdParty.h` and `Wrapper.h` needs to be added in the `Additional include directories`.Separate the two paths with a semicolon.

3,After checking and the modification, when you try to build the Principal, make sure that the Wrapper has been successfully built

Comment: Check, check and check, unfortunately (I added the include in the `.cpp` file in my question so that it would fit the minimum viable example mold)

Comment: I suggest you could try to add `#include"ThirdParty.h"` into the `Wrapper.h`.

Comment: I did too. Again, I just "added" them to the `.cpp` for MVE reasons